# GNU Make: How to export the SHELL variable to sub-makes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

From the GNU Make manual:

> The value of the make variable SHELL
>   is not exported. Instead, the value of
>   the SHELL variable from the invoking
>   environment is passed to the sub-make.
>   You can force make to export its value
>   for SHELL by using the export
>   directive, described below.

I must be doing something wrong, or not reading the manual properly, as this simple example doesn't work:

```
# ./Makefile
export SHELL := /bin/bash
export VALUE := exported_variable
$(info root makefile SHELL=$(SHELL))
call_sub_make:
    $(MAKE) --directory=subdir
```

And subdir/Makefile:

```
$(info subdir makefile SHELL=$(SHELL))
$(info subdir makefile VALUE=$(VALUE))
do_nothing:
```

Output:

```
$ env | grep SHELL
SHELL=/bin/bash
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
$ make
root makefile SHELL=/bin/bash
make --directory=subdir
subdir makefile SHELL=/bin/sh
subdir makefile VALUE=exported_variable
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/drtwox/C/make/export_shell/subdir'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `do_nothing'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/drtwox/C/make/export_shell/subdir'
```

VALUE is exported, why isn't SHELL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHELL is exported (to the sub-make's environment) alright, but [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell) also says

> Unlike most variables, the variable SHELL is never set from the environment.

If you want to influence the sub-make's idea of SHELL, you'll have to do it like this:

```
call_sub_make:
    $(MAKE) --directory=subdir SHELL=$(SHELL)
```